# No Directionality widget found

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a simple layout in `flutter` but keep getting this error:

> > The following assertion was thrown building Text("Deliver features faster", textAlign: center):
> >     No Directionality widget found.

I think the problem may be in the TextDirection class property, but I have been unable to find it.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main(){

  runApp( new MyHome());
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget{

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Material(
      child: new Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new Text('Deliver features faster', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Text('Craft beautiful UIs', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.contain, // otherwise the logo will be tiny
                child: const FlutterLogo(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the full stack trace of the error:

```
The following assertion was thrown building Text("Deliver features faster", textAlign: center):
No Directionality widget found.
RichText widgets require a Directionality widget ancestor.
The specific widget that could not find a Directionality ancestor was:
  RichText(textAlign: center, softWrap: wrapping at box width, maxLines: unlimited, text: "Deliver
  features faster")
The ownership chain for the affected widget is:
  RichText ← Text ← Expanded ← Row ← DecoratedBox ← Padding ← Container ← DefaultTextStyle ←
  AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ← _InkFeatures-[GlobalKey#978b7 ink renderer] ← ⋯
Typically, the Directionality widget is introduced by the MaterialApp or WidgetsApp widget at the
top of your application widget tree. It determines the ambient reading direction and is used, for
example, to determine how to lay out text, how to interpret "start" and "end" values, and to resolve
EdgeInsetsDirectional, AlignmentDirectional, and other *Directional objects.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      debugCheckHasDirectionality.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:223:7)
#1      debugCheckHasDirectionality (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:239:4)
#2      RichText.createRenderObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart:4245:37)
#3      RenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4259:28)
#4      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
#5      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
#6      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3636:16)
#7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3478:5)
#8      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3605:5)
#9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
#10     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
#11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
#12     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3636:16)
#13     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3478:5)
#14     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3605:5)
#15     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
#16     ParentDataElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3938:16)
#17     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
#18     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4738:32)
#19     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
#20     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
#21     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4633:14)
#22     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
#23     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
#24     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4633:14)
#25     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
#26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
#27     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3636:16)
#28     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3478:5)
#29     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3605:5)
#30     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
#31     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
#32     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
#33     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3636:16)
#34     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3478:5)
#35     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3605:5)
#36     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
#37     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
#38     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
#39     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3636:16)
#40     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3478:5)
#41     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3605:5)
#42     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3752:22)
#43     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
#44     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
#45     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
#46     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4633:14)
#47     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
#48     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
#49     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3636:16)
#50     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3478:5)
#51     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3605:5)
#52     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
#53     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
#54     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
#55     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4633:14)
#56     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
#57     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
#58     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3636:16)
#59     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3478:5)
#60     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3605:5)
#61     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3752:22)
#62     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
#63     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
#64     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
#65     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3636:16)
#66     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3478:5)
#67     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3605:5)
#68     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3752:22)
#69     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
#70     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
#71     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
#72     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3636:16)
#73     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3478:5)
#74     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3605:5)
#75     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3600:5)
#76     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2890:14)
#77     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2693:12)
#78     RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:852:16)
#79     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:823:5)
#80     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:769:17)
#81     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2205:19)
#82     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:768:13)
#83     BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:657:7)
#84     runApp (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:699:7)
#85     main (/data/user/0/com.yourcompany.flutterproject/cache/flutter_projectENWZDI/flutter_project/lib/main.dart:6:3)
#86     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:279)
#87     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:165)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Another exception was thrown: No Directionality widget found.
Another exception was thrown: Horizontal RenderFlex with multiple children has a null textDirection, so the layout order is undefined.
Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1446 pos 12: 'hasSize': is not true.
uid=10079(com.yourcompany.flutterproject) Thread-5 identical 2 lines
Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1446 pos 12: 'hasSize': is not true.
Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1564 pos 12: 'hasSize': is not true.
```

Comment: Please post what you came up with and further explain what should be the expected behaviour you are looking for

Answer (score 106):

flutter doesn't know whether the text is LTR or RTL, so you need to tell him the [textDirection](https://master-docs-flutter-io.firebaseapp.com/flutter/dart-ui/TextDirection-class.html) explicitly

```
Text("Hello", textDirection: TextDirection.ltr)
```

or you can just wrap the Text with a [Directionality](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html) Widget

```
Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          child: Text('Hello')
```

and the purpuse of that is :

> A widget that determines the ambient directionality of text and
> text-direction-sensitive render objects.

And a Text widget in the scope of a MaterialApp widget does not need to be given an explicit writing direction because The default localization in the widgets and material libraries is LTR

Answer (score 62):

If you don't use `MaterialApp` you need to wrap your app into some widgets yourself

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
...
runApp(
    new MediaQuery(
        data: new MediaQueryData.fromWindow(ui.window),
        child: new Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: new MyHome())))
```

Comment: TextDirection.rtl what is use of this line'

Comment: The `Directionality` widget needs to have a direction set. That's the main purpose of the widget.

Comment: this ans is right so i put them correct but now i seen that person copy and past your answer.

Comment: I am getting undefined name ui

Comment: You need to add `import 'dart:ui' as ui;`

Answer (score 42):

You get this error, if you're not using `MaterialApp` or `WidgetsApp` at the root level of your tree hierarchy.

**Solution:**

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(home: MyHome()), // use MaterialApp
  );
}

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold( // use Scaffold also in order to provide material app widgets
      body: Center(child: Text("Something")),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Correct with the reason of my error, but unfortunately the solution did not work! Any updates if possible? If something has changed!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not that you have not wrapped your widgets into MaterialApp. As the documentation says this error occurs due to the nesting of the same kind of Widgets like nesting of Row into Row, Column into Column or Column into ListView so the problem arises as it becomes unbounded constraints for the Widget so unable to identify the direction.

So to avoid this kind of problems usage of Flexible or Expanded occurs which identifies the remaining space.

In your case, you can simply give crossAxisAlignment with a value of `start` to the Row widget.

For more information, visit this [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) page

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a solution to original question but for similar other scenario.*

Totally agree with @CopsOnRoad's answer. Apart from that, there are scenarios you have to use `MaterialApp.router` option instead of `MaterialApp`. As an example, when we are using `go_router` plugin we may encounter this case.

For the happy path in the app development you will not get this issue with `MaterialApp.router` either. You will get this error if you try to write `WidgetTest` for this scenario. In that case one of the solutions is:

```
  testWidgets('Description', (widgetTester) async {
    await widgetTester.pumpWidget(const MaterialApp(
      home: YourScreen(),
    ));

    // rest of the code goes here
  });
```