# flutter: textDirection in textfield does not work

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[here is the result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42SJV.jpg)

dart code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/login.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: 'Please enter a search term1',
            ),
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

though i have already provided textDirection argument for TextField, but it still told

> I/flutter ( 5806): No Directionality widget found.
>
> I/flutter ( 5806): TextField widgets require a Directionality widget ancestor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if you would need to specify the `textDirection` at all. This may be not be required since you're using `Material` widget. **"...when the MaterialApp widget is used, this is taken care of for you,..."** from https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro.

But I found another SO answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49689947/4794396) that suggests try wrapping widget something like:

```
new Directionality(
     textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
     child: // your textField here?
     ....
     ....
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this works if you wrap your text field in `Directionality` widget.

Comment: then, why textDirection in TextField itself doesn't work, is it a bug?

Comment: @JianmingWan Could you add a screenshot for your original implementation?

Answer (score -1):

Simple way;

```
TextField(
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  ....,
)
```